# Google Cloud Datastore Transactions Implementation

Tags: node.js, concurrency, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

It is unclear for me, how the transactions implemented in google's datastore.

1. How they determines the resource I'm trying to reach? Because we are receiving global transaction object that we must use then for all requests. I have doubts, that this is done on the client library level, not on database level.
2. Is this transaction works both for read and write? I mean, that can I using the transaction implement document lock mechanism, so two user's cannot access it simultaneously (like mutex when we are dealing with multithreaded/multiprocessed applications).
3. And the final question. Does anybody know how the transnational mechanism implemented in datastore? I mean, high level architecture, or maybe processes diagrams, maybe short inside description, to get better understanding, what I am working with.

It shouldn't be relevant, but I'm using Google Cloud Functions and node.js environment for the project. I believe that this should not make any hard restrictions on usage.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but there is some good documentation on transactions with Cloud Datastore. I suggest you take a read through the concept documentation for this topic: [Transactions](http://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions)

1. Transactions are a database level concept (server-side).
2. Transactions do support reads and writes. It is implemented as optimistic locking, so it won't block another client from reading it like a mutex, but it will cause the transaction to fail and rollback as appropriate.
3. In the documentation it talks about the details that are relevant to using it.

> Outside of transactions, Cloud Datastore's isolation level is closest
>   to read committed. Inside of transactions, serializable isolation is
>   enforced. This means that another transaction cannot concurrently
>   modify the data that is read or modified by this transaction. Read the
>   [serializable isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability) wiki and the [Transaction Isolation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation) article for
>   more information on isolation levels.

Comment: Suppose we need to check if some resource is locked. So, client A and client B sends request to datastore inside transaction in order to check whether this resource already locked, or not. Will one of this requests fail in this case (when both reading)? If they both trying to write to datastore inside transaction, one of them, of course will fail to do that. But, if they miss just on one line of code, then, there is a chance, that both writes will be successful and client A will override record of the client B.

Comment: I just need continues document lock mechanism, in order to check, whether other user allowed to edit that document (reading is ok).